# Help calculating work done by stretching a wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, work, elasticity

> A wire of length 0.89 m and cross-sectional area 1.7 cm<sup>2</sup> is stretched elastically by an amount 1.2 cm. By Hooke’s law, the restoring force is $−k\Delta L$.
>
> Calculate the work done in stretching this wire by an amount $\Delta L$. Young's modulus is 1.3 $\times$ 10<sup>10</sup> N/m<sup>2</sup>

I don't really know where to start.

Comment: You start by deriving the force as a function of extension and then $W=\int F(x)\,{\rm d}x$

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the [Young's modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus) the Hook's law (up to the overall sign) is written as
$$F=ES \frac{\Delta L}{L_0}=kx, $$
the corresponding elastic energy (or the work that has be done to stretch a wire) is
$$W=ES \frac{\Delta L^2}{2L_0}, $$
here you know the Young's modulus $E=1.3 \times 10^{10}$, the cross area $S=1.7cm^2$ and the initial length $L_0=0.89m$ and the amount of stretching  $\Delta L=0.012 m$. Do not forget to transform the cross area into square meters!

Comment: Check your units. Force and Energy shouldn't have the same units. If $k=\frac{E S}{L_0}$ then $W=\frac{1}{2}k x^2$ and not $W=k x$

Comment: thank you for giving me minuses because of a typo, great job!

Comment: It ain't just a typo when the answer was totally wrong. Thanks for correcting.